# Does killing the priest in boss combat count against "no kill" ending?

Tags: vampyr

In Vampyr, at one stage you have a difficult boss fight with

> your transformed sister.

She drags your mother and a priest (that performed her funeral) to the fight - while you can save your mother, the priest will be used as a "snack" by your opponent, which will replenish her health.

However, you can make things easier for yourself by killing the priest before she does, to get his blood and heal yourself at the same time.

This priest is not mentioned anywhere on the "Citizen's list" for any district - but does it mean that you can kill him and receive the best ending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by no kill you mean the "not even once" achievement, than I think, the answer is yes. After a bit of reasearch, it seems to me, that this [site](https://www.reddit.com/r/Vampyr/comments/8qlggj/specific_question_about_the_last_boss_in_chapter_3/) gives the most helpful answer to your question, since someone has accidentally done it, and even after a restart still saw the consequence of it in his/her EXP. In the same site, if you open the comment section, there is a comment that states that they actually tried it on second play-through, and thanks to that didn't get the trophy.

Comment: Hmm, but are the requirements for the trophy and the best ending the same?

Comment: Spoiler warning! on [this](https://segmentnext.com/2018/06/09/vampyr-endings-guide/) site is the official endings guide. Here it mentions two good endings, one of which does indeed also require the "not even once" achievement.